# Cross-ratio concept from Euclidean Geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I have seen on the following Wikipedia website the definition of "cross-product." Apparently, if four lines passing through a common point $P$ are traversed by a line and the points of intersection "in one direction" are A, B, C, and D, their cross-product is
\begin{equation*}
[A, B; C, D] = \frac{\mathit{AC}\cdot \mathit{BD}}{\mathit{AD} \cdot \mathit{BC}} .
\end{equation*}
Why is this quantity defined this way? Is there supposed to be a semicolon in this notation? If another line intersects the same four lines passing through $P$ at $A^{\prime}$, $B^{\prime}$, $C^{\prime}$, and $D^{\prime}$ "in the same direction,"
\begin{equation*}
[A, B; C, D] = [A^{\prime}, B^{\prime}; C^{\prime}, D^{\prime}] .
\end{equation*}
What is a proper explanation for this? What happens if the points $A^{\prime}$, $B^{\prime}$, $C^{\prime}$, and $D^{\prime}$ "in the opposite direction" with respect to $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio

May someone offer me a textbook in Euclidean Geometry that has a discussion on cross-product?

Comment: Do you know anything about projective geometry? It would be easier to answer the question if you do have some basic familiarity. Otherwise I could recommend some lecture notes.

Comment: Here is a good video on cross-ratio on YouTube by NJ Wildberger: (https://youtu.be/-lkxvIJNnEc) I believe he has a whole series on projective geometry. **Caution:** He does have some extremely unconventional views on mathematics, like he doesn't believe in real numbers. Regardless, his series on projective geometry is good.

Comment: “Cross-ratio,” not “cross product.”

Answer (score 3):

The cross-ratio of four points $A,B,C$ and $D$ on a line $l$ in Euclidean space is defined as the *ratio* of the ratios $AC:BC$ and $AD:BD$. Simplifying the double quotient yields
$$ [A,B;C,D] = \frac{\frac{AC}{BC}}{\frac{AD}{BD}} = \frac{AC\cdot BD}{AD \cdot BC}.$$
The semicolon in Wikipedia's notation indicates the different roles of $A,B$ and $C,D$ here.

Now, if $P$ is a fifth point with distance $d$ to $l$, we can express $[A,B;C,D]$ via the areas of the triangles $[PAC]$, $[PBC]$, $[PAD]$ and $[PBD]$:
$$ [A,B;C,D] =  \frac{\frac{AC \cdot d}{2} \cdot \frac{ BD \cdot d}{2}}{\frac{AD \cdot d }{2}\cdot \frac{BC \cdot d}{2}} =
\frac{[PAC] \cdot [PBD]}{[PAD] \cdot [PBC]},$$
which by the sine area theorem can be written as
$$ [A,B;C,D] = \frac{PA \cdot PC \cdot \sin(PA,PC) \cdot PB \cdot PD \cdot \sin(PB,PD)}{PA \cdot PD \cdot \sin(PA,PD) \cdot PB \cdot PC \cdot \sin(PB,PC)} = 
\frac{\sin(PA,PC) \cdot \sin(PB,PD)}{\sin(PA,PD) \cdot \sin(PB,PC)}.$$
where $\sin(PX,PY)$ denotes the oriented angle between the lines $PX$ and $PY$.
Remarkably, this expression does only depend on the angle between the four lines $PA$, $PB$, $PC$ and $PD$, and not at all on how $l$ intersects these. 
Therefore, if $A', B', C'$ and $D'$ are four different points on $PA,PB,PC$ and $PD$ on another line $l'$, we will have
$$[A,B;C,D] = \frac{\sin(PA,PC) \cdot \sin(PB,PD)}{\sin(PA,PD) \cdot \sin(PB,PC)} = 
 \frac{\sin(PA',PC') \cdot \sin(PB',PD')}{\sin(PA',PD') \cdot \sin(PB',PC')} = [A',B';C',D'].$$
Note that if $A$ and $A'$ lie on different sides of $P$, both $\sin(PA,PC)$ and $\sin(PA,PD)$ change sign, thus leaving the crossratio invariant.

A very practically oriented chapter on Euclidean cross-ratios would be in Evan Chen's "Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads". Of course, one can study projective geometry much more abstractly, which is detailed in most textbooks on linear algebra.

Comment: I appreciate you providing an explanation. I will be looking at it.(I apologize for the delayed response.)  A couple of days after you suggested it, I did purchase the book Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads by Evan Chen. I am still waiting for it to arrive.